Can't start the resource manager and node manager with the older version of Java
I have 3 versions of Java currently installed, and I'm currently using JDK 9.0.1 to work with Hadoop 3.4.0. Although I have explicitly set the JAVA_HOME to point to the directory of 9.0.1, when I use start-all.cmd, hadoop still picks the JDK 17.0.11 as default, and hence, there was the compatibility error
This is the image when I started the Resource Manager
enter image description here
This is the set up of my JAVA_HOME
enter image description here
My path variable is at the top level
enter image description here
Running command java -version
enter image description here
I can only started the Name Node and the Data Node, it failed to launch for the Resource Manager and the Node Manager
enter image description here
Below is the main error that I have cut out for launching the Resource Manager
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:79)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$MethodWrapper
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DuplicatesPredicate.evaluate(DuplicatesPredicate.java:104)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$CollectionUtils.filter(CollectionUtils.java:52)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClassEmitter.<init>(FastClassEmitter.java:69)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.generateClass(FastClass.java:77)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:332)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:96)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:94)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61)
        ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:79)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:119)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:294)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.create(FastClass.java:65)
        at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClassForMember(BytecodeGen.java:258)
        at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClassForMember(BytecodeGen.java:207)
        at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.create(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:49)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProxyFactory.create(ProxyFactory.java:156)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.createConstructor(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:94)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.access$000(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:30)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:38)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:34)
        at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache$1.load(FailableCache.java:43)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3528)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2277)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2154)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2044)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$MethodWrapper
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DuplicatesPredicate.evaluate(DuplicatesPredicate.java:104)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$CollectionUtils.filter(CollectionUtils.java:52)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClassEmitter.<init>(FastClassEmitter.java:69)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.generateClass(FastClass.java:77)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:332)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:96)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:94)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61)
        ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Exception com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException-->Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @5bf0d49 [in thread "main"]
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:464)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:339)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:96)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:94)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:119)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:294)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:221)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:174)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:157)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:149)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:145)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$MethodWrapper.<clinit>(MethodWrapper.java:23)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DuplicatesPredicate.evaluate(DuplicatesPredicate.java:104)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$CollectionUtils.filter(CollectionUtils.java:52)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClassEmitter.<init>(FastClassEmitter.java:69)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.generateClass(FastClass.java:77)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:332)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:96)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:94)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:119)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:294)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.create(FastClass.java:65)
        at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClassForMember(BytecodeGen.java:258)
        at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClassForMember(BytecodeGen.java:207)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.create(ProviderMethod.java:69)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethodsModule.createProviderMethod(ProviderMethodsModule.java:327)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethodsModule.getProviderMethods(ProviderMethodsModule.java:135)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethodsModule.configure(ProviderMethodsModule.java:105)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:347)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:356)
        at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.install(AbstractModule.java:103)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletModule.configure(ServletModule.java:49)
        at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:61)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:347)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:104)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:137)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:105)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2050)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3952)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3974)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4958)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4964)
        at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:54)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.get(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:49)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.initialize(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:155)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:592)
        at com.google.inject.internal.AbstractBindingProcessor$Processor.initializeBinding(AbstractBindingProcessor.java:173)
        at com.google.inject.internal.AbstractBindingProcessor$Processor.lambda$scheduleInitialization$0(AbstractBindingProcessor.java:160)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProcessedBindingData.initializeBindings(ProcessedBindingData.java:49)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:124)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:108)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:87)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:69)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:59)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebApps$Builder.build(WebApps.java:420)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebApps$Builder.start(WebApps.java:468)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebApps$Builder.start(WebApps.java:464)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.webapp.WebServer.serviceStart(WebServer.java:125)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:79)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:119)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:294)
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.create(FastClass.java:65)
        at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClassForMember(BytecodeGen.java:258)
        at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClassForMember(BytecodeGen.java:207)
        at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.create(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:49)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProxyFactory.create(ProxyFactory.java:156)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.createConstructor(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:94)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.access$000(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:30)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:38)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:34)
        at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache$1.load(FailableCache.java:43)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3528)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2277)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2154)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2044)
        ... 25 more

I have tried to even configure the hadoop-env, but it doesn't work. I don't know if I just should delete that JDK 17.10.11 version or downgrade my current Hadoop version
